# 401 - Unauthorized when fetching data from Django REST framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

I need to fetch a list of emails from Django REST Framework, I'm working with such requests for the first time so I have a little clue how to do this. I'm running the following code:

```
fetch("http://68.183.74.14:4005/api/emails/")
.then((response) => console.log(response))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

And I get an error 401 - Unauthorized:

[image]

I have login, email and password and the following URLs:

```
Endpoints: http://68.183.74.14:4005/swagger/
Base request URL: http://68.183.74.14:4005/api/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The the `body` have any error message from rest-framework?

Comment: well, that url required authentication, which you are not providing.in your fetch call.

Comment: @OldProgrammer. So how can I provide authentication?

Comment: Well, what does the documentation for the API state as the requirements?  There are different authentication methods.  Do you have an account username/password? https://code-boxx.com/javascript-fetch-auth/   https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/  If you browse to http://68.183.74.14:4005/api/emails/ you will see the browser is prompting for basic authentication.  So try with your credentials, and if that works, then add that to your fetch call

Comment: It uses 'Basic authentication' method, I logged in in both URLs, where can I now find the credentials?

Comment: See the link I posted in the comments on how to add basic auth to a fetch call